# How to make a tiled steps slip proof

Tags: tile, stairs

I have three steps in backyard which has Cool roof tiles laid on top of it.

Please find more information about the tile.

[image]

[image]

Since the tile is skid and scratch resistant , I used the remaining tiles from terrace floor on the backyard steps.

When my mom was stepping, she got slipped recently.

What can I do to make the Tile step slip proof ?

Comment: Was there anything(slime, oil,ice) on the floor that would have reduced skid resistance?  Making it slip/skid proof maybe some covering with sand embedded.

Comment: @crip659 - Her feet might have had moisture as she walked on bare foot. Is there anything we can do to improve skid resistance ? Sand embedded ? could you detail this a bit ?

Comment: Something like a paint/epoxy covering that you sprinkle sand on before it dries.  There should be other solutions also someone else might point to.  It will depend on how much you want to do.  I imagine one consideration of choosing that tile was for looks.

Comment: Ok , Thanks for your suggestion anyways

Comment: Note that condition of shoes also matters. I had one set of rubber-soled slippers which had worn flat enough to be slippery when the deck was wet...

Comment: Some kind of adhesive stair strips?

Comment: @Huesmann - Will it last long enough ? and endure the rain water ?

Comment: @CuriousMan yes, you can get outdoor rated products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tiles say they are skid resistant, but obviously not enough.

Add some anti-slip strips like [these](https://www.amazon.com/non-skid-strips/s?k=non%20skid%20strips).

Comment: Anti slip strips , will it last long enough and withstand rain ?

Comment: There are outdoor rated products that are made to stay stuck in the rain.  You will have to check the specs of the product you choose.